# @if ($errors->any()) : try to create an application thanks to Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

I tried to connect ma database to my frontend, but it doesn't work. I am working with Laravel and my localhost database.

- Data source: apps@localhost
- Dialect: MariaDB
- DBMS: MySQL
- Case sensitivity: plain=exact, delimited=exact
- Driver: MySQL Connector/J
- Effective version: MariaDB

This is my code for the `resources/views/apps.blade.php`:

```php
@extends('base')

@section('title', 'Création d\'une piscine')

@section('content')
<form method="post" action="{{route('pool.store')}}" novalidate>
    @csrf
    @if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        La piscine n'a pas pu être ajouté &#9785;
    </div>
    @endif
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="longueur">Longueur</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="longueur" name="longueur" min="0" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="largeur">Largeur</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="largeur" name="largeur" min="0" required>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Soumettre</button>
</form>
@endsection
```

And then `routes/web.php`:

```php
Route::get('/pools/create', [Controller::class, 'createPool'])->name('pool.create');
Route::post('/pools', [Controller::class, 'storePool'])->name('pool.store');
Route::get('/pools/{id_pool}', [Controller::class, 'showPool'])->where('id_pool', '[0-9]+')->name('pool.show');
```

And `Repository.php`:

```php
function createDatabase(): void 
{
    DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('database/build.sql'));
}
//test et order des piscines
function pools(): array
{
    return DB::table('pools')->orderBy('id','asc')->get()->toArray();
}
//Insertion des données
function insertPool(array $pool): int
{
    return DB::table('pools')->insertGetId($pool);
}

function poolInfo($id_pool)
{
    //retourne le tableau des matchs auxquels une équipe participe, triés par date
    $pools = DB::table('pools')
        ->where('id_pool',$id_pool)
        ->get(['pools.*', 'longueur as longueur', 'largeur as largeur'])
        ->toArray();

    return $pools;
}
```

Then, the `controller.php`:

```php
public function storePool(Request $request)
{

    if($request->session()->has("user"))
    {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
    $rules = [
        'type' => ['required'],
        'longueur' => ['required', 'integer'],
        'largeur' => ['required', 'integer']
    ];

    $messages = [
        'type.required' => 'Vous devez choisir un type de piscine.',
        'longueur.required' => 'Vous devez choisir une longueur.',
        'largeur.required' => 'Vous devez choisir une largeur.'
    ];
    $validatedData = $request->validate($rules,$messages);
    try {
        // appels aux méthodes de l'objet de la classe Repository
        $poolId= $this->repository->insertPool
        (['longueur' => $validatedData['longueur'],
            'largeur' => $validatedData['largeur']]);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        return redirect()->route('pool.create')->withInput()->withErrors("Impossible de créer le match.");
    }
    return redirect()->route('pool.show', ['id_pool' => $poolId]);
}

public function createPool(Request $request)
{
    return view('pool_create');
}

public function showPool(int $id_pool)
{
    $pools=$this->repository->poolInfo($id_pool);
    return view('pools', ['pools' => $pools]);
}
```

And the database:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pools;

CREATE TABLE pools(
    id_pool INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    longueur INT,
    largeur  INT,
);
```

When I click on button "submit", nothing happens. I just get a little text from my code `apps.blade.php`:

```php
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
        La piscine n'a pas pu être ajouté &#9785;
    </div>
@endif
```

If you need more information, I can give you more with pleasure. I am just starting to learn how to code.

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at the Laravel documentation, getting started. Find out how Laravel connects to the db. How to create tables using migrations. How Eloquent ORM works. That is a lot easier.

Comment: For a start, show the errors. `<ul> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach </ul>`

Comment: Hello, yes, thanks to you, I found the problem. They give me the message error : Impossible de créer la piscine. And this is in my Controller.php : "        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return redirect()->route('pool.create')->withInput()->withErrors("Impossible de créer la piscine.");
        }
        return redirect()->route('pool.show', ['id_pool' => $poolId]);"